# 400 Bad Request on socket

Tags: python, python-3.x

when i run the code and enter the hyperlink for example users.uop.gr/~kyianno/ i get 400 BAD REQUEST. It suppose to achieve GET and return 200 OK and then download a response.html to desktop, but i always get 400 bad request. Can't figure it out.

```
import socket
import struct
import os

def parse_hyperlink(hyperlink):
    hostname = hyperlink.split("/")[0]
    object_name = "/".join(hyperlink.split("/")[1:])
    return hostname, object_name

def get_host_address(hostname):
    host_address = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
    return host_address

def main():
    hyperlink = input("Enter a hyperlink: ")
    hostname, object_name = parse_hyperlink(hyperlink)
    host_address = get_host_address(hostname)

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.connect((host_address, 80))

    request = "GET " + object_name + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
    request += "Host: " + hostname + "\r\n"
    request += "\r\n"

    server_socket.sendall(request.encode("utf-8"))

    response = b""
    while True:
        data = server_socket.recv(255)
        if not data:
            break
        response += data

    status_code = struct.unpack("!H", response[:2])[0]
    if status_code == 200:
        desktop_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop")
        directory = os.path.join(desktop_path, "my_directory")
        if not os.path.exists(directory):
            os.makedirs(directory)
            file_path = os.path.join(directory, "response.html")

        with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(response[2:])

    print(response.decode("utf-8"))

    server_socket.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you printed out the `object_name` and `hostname`?  A command line `telnet` session works, surprisingly even with HTTP (no need for HTTPS).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that by supplying `users.uop.gr/~kyianno/`, the `object_name` becomes `~kyianno/` and this is not string to provide to the GET request. By curl you can see, GET issues to resource starting with `/`:

```
> GET /~kyianno/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: users.uop.gr
> User-Agent: curl/8.2.1
> Accept: */*
```

to make your code work, you need to add a `/` in the below line. From:

```
request = "GET " + object_name + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

to:

```
request = "GET /" + object_name + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix. It was obvious but needed clear eyes.